# How do I recursively touch files matching a pattern

Tags: linux, touch

Within my ~/docs directory, I want to "touch" all files ending with .txt

How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With `find`:

```
find ~/docs -name "*.txt" -exec touch {} \;
```

- You search in `~/docs`
- The `name` option will match all `txt` files
  - `exec` will execute the command `touch` on the file name, which is substituted in `{}`
- `\;` ends the command and `touch` will be called once for each file found

Note:

- A slight variation, `\+` at the end constructs one single command to run `touch` on all of these files at once. This is not possible with all commands, but it works for `touch` and saves you a few calls if you have a lot of files that are affected.

Comment: `{} \+` would be better here... `touch` can handle many filenames on its  command line, so for example, with 10 thousand files and `{} \;` **10 thousand** calls will be made to `touch`... Using `{} \+` will call `touch` only once (depending on available memory)...  Here is an excerpt from *find's* man-page: `-exec command {} + ... The command line is built in much the same way that xargs builds its command lines`. There is more detail in the `man find` documentation.

Comment: @Peter.O True, just a habit of mine to use the other syntax.

Comment: @slhck: And much slower with higher overhead.